# How to loop while following-char equals string?

Tags: function, loops, emacs

I am writing a function to uncomment regardless of mode. I want to delete all comment characters at the beginning of a line.

How do I make the snippet below loop until the following character is not equal to comment-start? (so basically have this "if" go on and on and on until `following-char` is not equal to `comment-start` anymore)

```
(if (string= (byte-to-string (following-char)) comment-start)
   (progn (delete-forward-char 1) 
          (when (string= (byte-to-string (following-char)) " ") 
               (delete-forward-char 1))))
```

Comment: why not just use, uncomment-region `M-;`

Comment: Because that uncomment-region only works for region. This also uncomments the comment character on the current line, regardless of where point is at.

Comment: @kindahero which for me is uesful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A while loop was easier than I thought:

```
(defun uncomment-mode-specific ()  
  "Uncomment region OR uncomment beginning of line comment OR uncomment end"
  (interactive)
  (if (region-active-p)
      (uncomment-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
    (back-to-indentation))
  (setq scvar 0)
  (setq scskipvar 0)
  (while (= scvar 0) 
     (if (string= (byte-to-string (following-char)) comment-start)
         (progn (delete-forward-char 1) 
            (when (string= (byte-to-string (following-char)) " ") 
                      (delete-forward-char 1))
            (setq scskipvar 1))
       (setq scvar 1)))
  (if (= scskipvar 0)
      (progn (search-forward comment-start nil t)
         (left-char 1)
         (kill-line))
    )
)
```